# VBA - executing code from a string in array

Tags: arrays, vba, string

So I have an 2 arrays in my code (both of which are numeric), lets call them Array1 and Array2.

Array1 contains formula as a string, this needs to be calculated from Array2, for example:

```
Array1(5) = "Array2(1)+Array2(3)"
```

What I need is to find the numeric value for Array1(5), so need to actually execute what's in `Array1(5)`.

Can this be done?

Thank you,

Joe

Comment: This looks very very much like an X-Y problem. You never, **never** *NEED* to do this. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: So the report needs to be able to calculate the formula inputted by a user.
So for the above example, let's say I have an array which is 6 long and is:


(1,5,2,3,,4).

The user can input '5' = '1' + '3'

Then the VBA code will actually read in that formula as:

Array1(5) = Array1(1) + Array1(3)

The difficulty is that I also need this to work with formula like '1'/'3', '1' + '3' + '4' etc.

Comment: You might have more success parsing the user input into a binary expression tree, computing the result by traversing the tree structure. This would be done with *nodes*, not string arrays. Or, just send the user-input string expression to `Application.Evaluate`, but then the expression must be a valid Excel formula and works in the context of whatever the active sheet is.

Comment: Essentially you're writing an expression evaluation engine... not something that's easy to do in VBA. If you can use C# or Python or Java, you could use Antlr to define a formal grammar for your domain-specific expression language, generate a parser, give it the user input, and get an abstract syntax tree that you can then traverse to evaluate each node and calculate the result. This isn't a simple problem to solve, but yes, it can be done - even in VBA.

Comment: Entire books have been written on this subject - this question is currently too broad to be correctly answerable here IMO. Feel free to ask a more specific question if you're stuck on any particular problem, showing your failing attempt(s) and a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. Good luck!